# Codeigniter next_row() returns null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to get the next row everytim ei run the function but it always returns 0

Model

```
function getNextMuziek($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get('muziek')->num_rows() == 1;
        return $query->next_row();
    }
```

Comment: dup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344342/codeigniter-next-record-in-the-database

Comment: that didnt got solved nor attention

Comment: That doesn't mean you can repost it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter next record in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344342/codeigniter-next-record-in-the-database)

Comment: please delete your previous question then. it is very bad form to repost questions when you feel they haven't gotten enough traction.

Comment: done ur welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html), `next_row()` is to be used to navigate through a result set. This will not serve your purposes. If you want your function to return the next row after the row specified by $id, the easiest thing would be to use a greater than comparison and return the first row. You could modify your code to

```
$query = $this->db->where('id >', $id)->limit(1)->get('muziek');
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: I used this and now i get: Call to undefined method stdClass::next_row()

Comment: @arnekick Let me do some testing and get back to you.

Comment: i would suggest adding a `$this->db->limit(1)` as well as a `num_rows() == 1` check before accessing `row()` as we don't know if there will be a higher row. otherwise this should be the accepted answer. also the `next_row()` documentation is hideous ... someone should fix it.

Comment: I get another error now for the num rows: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::num_rows()

Comment: I edited it again i think this is correct and now i have this error: Call to a member function next_row() on integer

Comment: @arnekick review the answer and see that next_row() is not used.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked is it maybe possible to adjust that code so when im on the last row it jumps to the first? Now when its on the last row it stays on the last row. And i really have no clue on how to do that.